# Symfony 3 and Angular 2 Folder Structure

Tags: php, angular, symfony

I am new to both Symfony and Angular and I am trying figure out how the pieces will fit together. I want to user Symfony for my back end and web api. I want to use Angular for the front end desktop like experiences.

I am not sure how the folder structure should be. Do I put my angular javascript/typescript files in folders in the root of the Symfony project and utilize their folder structure. Or do i have two bundles in my src folder. One for the back end/website. Another for the front end? Or should the back end be serving twig templates with angular components inserted?

***** Edit *****

@Tobias Xy Correct me if I'm wrong but that would be creating bundle in the src folder and keeping the files in a resources folders in it correct?

Then i see the following at the bottom:

> Frontend-Based Applications
>
> Recently, frontend technologies like AngularJS have become pretty
>   popular for developing frontend web applications that talk to an API.
>
> If you are developing an application like this, you should use the
>   tools that are recommended by the technology, such as Bower and
>   GruntJS. You should develop your frontend application separately from
>   your Symfony backend (even separating the repositories if you want).

So they are saying make two seperate projects and not use a bundle for the front end?

If so how do you host this? On two different sites?

Comment: I think he's saying that you shoud have 2 projects. One, with Symfony, as you stated, for an API, server side, and another project, with angular, front end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Symfony is a backend framework, so there is no point in adding a bundle containing only frontend files (css, javascript, etc).

See also [Web Assets (Symfony Best Practices)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html)

They say there:

> Store your assets in the web/ directory.

**Update 23.03.2016**

Cerad wrote in the comments: "client-side angularjs and reactjs apps have their own build system just like Symfony does".
This is actually a different topic, but the article I linked to above also says something about that:

> Recently, frontend technologies like AngularJS have become pretty popular for developing frontend web applications that talk to an API.
>
> If you are developing an application like this, you should use the tools that are recommended by the technology, such as Bower and GruntJS. You should develop your frontend application separately from your Symfony backend (even separating the repositories if you want).

Comment: While Symfony 2 is indeed a back end framework it is often used to build web applications.  I don't have a one size fits all directory structure but will often have a src-client directory for client side programs.

Comment: Of course it is used to build web applications. What else would you use it for? What I wanted to say here is, that Symfony focuses the serverside (i.e. backend) part of your website. In my opinion their explanation why you should put in the web directory makes totally sense, but obviously you can put your assets where ever you want, since putting it in the web directory is "only" a best practice.

Comment: My point was that client-side angularjs and reactjs apps have their own build system just like Symfony does.  The final assets will indeed end up under web but the actual source code will almost certainly be elsewhere.  But I think we are getting off topic.

Answer (score 2):

For Angular 2 there might be differences in the front end build system, but the structure should be similar to the one I use for Angular 1.x.

The folder structure I use to place my front end assets in something we could describe as a three level process. Let's just enumerate the three levels here:

**Level 1 - The `src/AppBundle/Resources/Private` folder**

Inside this folder, I place any front end assets that need any kind of processing, like transpile, autoprefix, uglify, etc. This will be the case for most JS, SCSS, LESS or HTML files of your choice. You can define the folder structure you prefer.

**Level 2 - The `src/AppBundle/Resources/Public` folder**

This will be the folder that'll contain all assets after processing AND any other asset that didn't need processing, usually images, fonts, etc. This will be the folder structure that will literally be copied over to the web/bundles/app folder in Level 3.

Note: This level is indeed redundant and can be skipped with caution. In my case, I kept it to avoid 'accidents' with the way Symfony wants to install assets by default, which will replace your `web/bundles/app` folder with the contents of this one. This will be the case if you use any other bundle that installs assets this way, like `FOSJsRoutingBundle` for example.

**Level 3 - The `web/bundles/app` folder**

This is the final public destination of your assets, and the path where you'll reference them in your code. It is just a copy of the `src/AppBundle/Resources/Public` folder from level 2.

**Build system**

You will need a front end build system to transpile your files and copy them to the respective folders in level 2 and 3. In my case for Angular 1.x I used Gulp with Node. This means you'll have gulpfile.js file, package.json file and node_modules folder in your project. I didn't care, it worked fine. Just remember to not add node_modules folder to your repo.

**In production**

Unless you really need to rebuild in production for some reason, you can skip level 1, level 2 and gulp related folders and files like node_modules, gulpfile.js, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the client side as the root document and the server side as an alias location, but careful to not overwrite the alias.
Or you could change the host.

Example 1:

```
[client]   www.example.com/<client_root_dir>
[server]   www.example.com/api/<server_root_dir>
```

or Example 2:

```
[client]   www.example.com/<client_root_dir>
[server]   api.example.com/<server_root_dir>
```